# Unity launcher placement stuck on all displays

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, launcher, display

I am using three monitors with Ubuntu 14.04. In **Display** settings, I try to change the *Launcher Placement* setting to only select one monitor. The monitors flicker, but even though the setting now might display one monitor name, the Launcher bar still appears on all three monitors. Similarly, I turn off *Sticky edges* but edges remain sticky. After I click *Apply* and restart **Display** settings, I see that the changes haven't been saved and revert to showing *All displays* in the **Display** settings.

I am wondering if this is because some configuration file isn't being written. Where is the configuration stored for the Launcher bar? Anyone have additional ideas what might be causing this setting not to change?